# How to store large numbers without losing precision?

Tags: sqlite

I'm looking to store very large numbers in an SQLite database (like 10^26), but cannot afford to lose precision of numbers. Which datatype to choose?

Comment: text string, thats how sqlite stores all data types anyway

Comment: @BigP: How are you characterizing these large numbers in your application? What OS are you running on? There are solutions, but you need to provide more information.

Comment: @pm100 That's completely wrong. SQLite stores both text and binary data. It does not store binary data as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare you column as BLOB or TEXT, and TEXT is probably more suitable to your application.